# Upgrading brew causes uninstalled elasticsearch package to reinstall

Tags: elasticsearch, homebrew

### Problem

I would like to switch to `elasticsearch 5.1.2` from `elasticsearch 2.4.4`. However, when I try to use brew to uninstall the package, it always reinstalls when I run brew upgrade.

### System

`Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.6`

### Example

I run this command: `brew uninstall elasticsearch@2.4`

I get these results: `Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch@2.4/2.4.4... (59 files, 29.1M)`

But when I run: `brew update && brew upgrade`

I get this:

```
Already up-to-date.
Already up-to-date.
==> Upgrading 1 outdated package, with result:
elasticsearch@2.4 2.4.4
==> Upgrading elasticsearch@2.4
==> Using the sandbox
==> Downloading https://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/release/org/elasticsearch/distribution/tar/elasticsearch/2.4.4/elasticsearch-2.4.4.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/wrburgess/Library/Caches/Homebrew/elasticsearch@2.4-2.4.4.tar.gz
==> Caveats
Data:    /usr/local/var/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_wrburgess/
Logs:    /usr/local/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_wrburgess.log
Plugins: /usr/local/opt/elasticsearch@2.4/libexec/plugins/
Config:  /usr/local/etc/elasticsearch/
plugin script: /usr/local/opt/elasticsearch@2.4/libexec/bin/plugin

To have launchd start elasticsearch@2.4 now and restart at login:
  brew services start elasticsearch@2.4
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  elasticsearch
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch@2.4/2.4.4: 59 files, 29.1M, built in 3 seconds
```

### Outcome

I'd like to have elasticsearch 2.4.4 completely removed from my system and switch to 5.1.2

Answer (score 3):

### On Further Analysis

running `brew list --versions` revealed that I still had `elasticsearch24 2.4.2` installed, which was the actual package causing the problem.

Thus, I had to run an uninstall command of `brew uninstall elasticsearch24`, which removed the last package.

I followed up with `brew cleanup -s` to clear any caches and everything seems to be working.